# trapeze stuck at required variable: BUILD_NUMBER

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm using [Trapeze](https://trapeze.dev/) to run my CI/CD, together with the ionic [capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/) library.

Somehow the process get stuck on `[?] Required variable: BUILD_NUMBER`.
I'm using the `BUILD_NUMBER` variable to store the `package.json` version. *(example 5.0.1-0)*

How can I fix that or what may be the reason of this bug

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, trapeze does not work with the version being `5.0.1-0`,
`-0` being the problem here.

Updating it to `5.0.1-1` made it work.